# NavigationView set colour to some of the icons

Tags: android, layout, navigationview, bottomnavigationview

I got a `NavigationView` and I want some of the icons to have colour.

[image]

I tried using `mNavigationView.setItemIconTintList(null);` but this makes all icons black. I create the the items which I want to have a colour at runtime:

```
SubMenu sub = menu.addSubMenu(GROUP_ID, GROUP_ID, 0, R.string.jobs);
for(int i = 0; i< jobs.size(); i++){
    MenuItem menuItem = sub.add(GROUP_ID, i, i, jobs.get(i).name);
    menuItem.setIcon(new ColorDrawable(Color.RED));
}
```

Is there a way to keep the IconColorTint list but remove it from some?

Comment: Color of icons is gonna change or it will be static?

Comment: The colors can change

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way by disabling the filter and settings a filter directly on the drawable.

```
navigationView.setItemIconTintList(null);
for (int iconId: filterIcons) {
    MenuItem menuItem = navigationView.getMenu().findItem(iconId);
    Drawable d = menuItem.getIcon().mutate();
    d.setColorFilter(Color.rgb(117, 117, 117), PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
    menuItem.setIcon(d);
}
```